# Перехватить ответ от удаленного веб-сервиса

Tags: c#, .net, soap, service, wcf

Доброго дня, уважаемые форумчане, такой вопрос.
Можно ли как-то перехватить в VS 2013 ответ от удаленного сервиса, до того как он начал обрабатываться в `ServiceReference`? 
С целью замены некоторых параметров (необходимо произвести приведение параметра к типу `DateTime.SpecifyKind`, а не как создано в `ServiceReference DateTime`).

**к коментарию:**

Зачем работать с классом с генерированным студией напрямую? Почему не сделать класс обертку, который, например, будет преобразовывать полученные от веб-сервиса данные в ваши пользовательские типы и, скажем, заодно заниматься преобразованием времени с учетом часовых поясов.

Если честно, слабо представляю, как так сделать, чтобы ответ шел сперва в мой класс, преобразовывались нужные параметры и потом уже только в Service reference... Во всем вина моего опыта:( к сожалению, с трудом представляю, как это можно сделать:(

**Обновление**

Вот в чем проблема: 1. Подключился к удаленному web-сервису. В папке Service References у меня этот сервис называется Service. 2. Обращаюсь к методу GetData сервиса Service. var result=service.GetData; 3. В переменную result приходит информация, и есть поле Date формата DateTime. При запросе через SOAPSonar мне приходит строка 2014-08-25T20:45:00+07:00, но при точно таком же запросе в VS 2013 я вижу дату 2014-08-25 17:45:00. То есть у нас смещение по времени 2 часа (в зависимости, какой часовой пояс выставлен на компьютере). Решил пока вопрос тем, что в самом Service я полям назначил значение string.

И уже в переменной result изменяю дату, как мне надо, но данный вариант имеет дикий минус, что если кто-то обновит Service,то и изменения эти удалятся и программа станет неработоспособной. Хотелось бы узнать, могу ли я перехватить ответ от удаленного сервиса, пока он не попал в Service и изменить поле Data так, как мне нужно, или как-то еще решить вопрос, не влазя в сервис. Надеюсь, описал проблему понятно:) А вот, что делать, не знаю( голова уже пухнет:(

Основная задача убрать влияние часового пояса при переводе поступившей даты в тип DateTime.

Comment: Может быть поможет http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb397769%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
рассматривал этот вариант, но тут же вопрос в том что в самом Service References сразу идет преобразование...и влазить туда и писать свое...ну я вот влез пока, костыль поставил string-ом(но это же не вариант походу...

Comment: Зачем работать с классом с генерированным студией напрямую? Почему не сделать класс обертку, который, например, будет преобразовывать полученные от веб сервиса данные в ваши пользовательские типы и скажем, заодно, заниматься преобразованием времени с учетом часовых поясов.

Answer (score 2):

> Если честно, слабо представляю, как так сделать, чтобы ответ шел сперва в мой класс, преобразовывались нужные параметры и потом уже только в Service reference... Во всем вина моего опыта:( к сожалению, с трудом представляю, как это можно сделать:(

Вы не совсем точно поняли, что имелось ввиду. Постараюсь объяснить по шагам.

**Первое**

На самом деле тут все предельно просто. Если вы работали с БД через ADO.NET, то должны понять принцип. В случае с БД вы сначала получали реляционные данные, которые затем преобразовывали в объектные. Здесь ситуация, в принципе, схожа, только вместо БД у вас веб-сервис, из которого вы получаете информацию.

**Второе**

Так как наверняка те типы данных, которые возвращает веб-сервис, вас не устроят в полном объеме, поскольку возвращенный тип может содержать кучу лишних и ненужных вам свойств, кроме того, с этим типом может быть неудобно работать. Следовательно, у вас должны быть определены свои пользовательские типы, с которыми осуществляется основная работа в приложении. Поэтому когда вы получаете от веб-сервиса данные, то устанавливаете соответствующие свойства ваших типов в зачения соответствующих свойств типа, возвращенного веб-сервисом. В принципе здесь, в момент установки значения, вы и можете осуществить преобразование даты с учетом часовых поясов. После того, когда данные будут преобразованы, они уходят на вышестояющий уровень, и с ними уже осуществляется работа далее.

**Третье**

В коде это может выглядеть примерно так:

```
  // Класс обертка, который преобразует
  // данные от веб сервиса в ваши типы.
  class Mapping
  { 
     // Класс веб сервиса, сгенерированный студией. 
     private Webservice webSer = new Webservice();

     // Метод, который возвращает некоторые данные,
     // полученные от вебсервиса и преобразованные 
     // в ваши типы.
     public List<MyClass> GetData()
     {
        // Получили от веб сервиса некоторые данные.
        var allData = webSer.GetData();

        // Результирующая переменная.
        List<MyClass> result = new List<MyClass>();

        // Проходим в цикле по всем данным,
        // полученным от веб сервиса.
        foreach(var data in allData)
        {
            // Создаем пользовательский объект.
            MyClass my = new MyClass()
            {
                  // Устанавливаем его свойства,
                  // в значения соответствующих свойств 
                  // типа, возвращенного веб сервисом.
                  // P.S. Здесь, например, вы можете осуществить 
                  // преобразование даты с учетом часовых поясов.
                  myDateProperty = data.DateProperty 
            };

             // Добавляем в результирующую коллекцию 
             // созданный объект.
             result.Add(my);    
       }

       // Возвращаем результат.
       return result;
   }
}
```